# How to inject dependencies on class extend

Tags: magento2, class, extend

can somebody explain when I extend another Block what is the way to inject dependencies? For example my Block is extending ListProduct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I inject into Some\Module\Model\SomeClass a new instance of CustomerMetadataInterface the key point to note is the type is set to object. Now in my class via the constructor I am able to obtain this class and use it as required:

```
class SomeClass 
{
    protected $metaDataInterface;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface $metaInterface) {
        $this->metaDataInterface = $metaInterface;
    }
}
```

More reference [here](http://magehero.com/posts/572/magento-2-dependency-injection)